# How to block gmail web chat with squid and iptables?

Tags: iptables, squid, gmail, instant-messaging

Is it possible to block just the web chat service and still use email service using iptables and squid or using either one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocking access to [chatenabled.mail.google.com](http://www.safesquid.com/html/viewtopic.php?t=2077) will stop users using the integrated web chat. Blocking connections to talk.google.com will stop users using the [google chat client](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=27930).

Blocking access to these locations won't affect using the email service. You can block the web chat in either iptables or squid. Since the standalone chat client uses jabber you will need to block those ports at the firewall.