# i want to block gtalk through squid

Tags: linux

can anybody suggest how to block gtak messenger thruogh squid without affecting other google
services .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to block gmail web chat with squid and iptables?](http://serverfault.com/questions/58301/how-to-block-gmail-web-chat-with-squid-and-iptables)

Answer (score 1):

Google Talk/Chat uses the following domains :

```
talk.google.com
talkx.google.com
talkgadget.google.com
chatenabled.mail.google.com
```

All you have to do is block them. You can use Squid or simply block the DNS lookup for those domains.

[Disabling Google Talk on my network](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/search.py?ctx=en:searchbox&query=%22Disabling+Google+Talk+on+my+network%22)

Answer (score 0):

You don't block gtalk through squid.

This is done in a firewall e.g. IPTables. An example can be found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/how-to-block-all-the-im-skype-googletalk-msn-yahoo-icq-363844/). All that you need to do is block the jabber port which is 5222 (but can go up till 5229).

Finally this is a question best suited for serverfault.com.